# Java: ¿Por qué no puedo borrar un elemento de un archivo .txt?

Tags: java

Que tal, amigos. Esperando se encuentren bien.

Tengo un problema con el manejo de archivos de texto en Java, el problema es el siguiente: yo guardo nombre y numero en un archivo de texto utilizando PrintWriter y FileWriter, le pido al usuario estos datos y los capturo ahí. Los agrega facilmente incluso los muestra en pantalla, el problema viene cuando necesito eliminar o editar los contactos, pido al usuario que ingrese el nombre del contacto que desea eliminar y hago la comparación para ver si son iguales o no, los muestro en pantalla y son el mismo nombre pero no logro hacer que elimine el contacto, a continuación el código:

El siguiente bloque de código muestra como elminar un contacto, pero quizás no sé como sobrescribir el contenido por espacio en blanco o solo eliminarlo.

```
public static void eliminarContacto(String nombre)
{

    try(Scanner entrada = new Scanner(new File("misContactos.txt")))
    {
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("misContactos.txt",true));
        String s [];
        boolean personaEncontrada = false;
        while(entrada.hasNextLine())
        {
            s = entrada.nextLine().split(":");
            if(s[0].equals(nombre))
            {
                System.out.println(s[0]);
                System.out.println(s[1]);
                System.out.println(nombre);
                s[0] = "";
                s[1] = "";
                pw.write(s[0]+" "+s[1]);
                System.out.println("Se ha borrado el contacto con nombre: "+nombre+".");
                personaEncontrada = true;
            }
        }
        if(!personaEncontrada)
        {
            System.out.println("No hay ningun con contacto con: "+nombre+" como nombre.");
        }
    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

De cualquier manera estoy a sus ordenes, cualquier duda la respondo. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pues mira, eso que haces de:

```
s[0] = "";
s[1] = "";
```

No está cambiando el archivo, sino el arreglo que llamaste `s`.
Es decir, estás modificando es el arreglo como tal, no el archivo.

Una solución a tu problema sería crear una clase donde almacenarás los datos de cada persona.

Una clase tipo:

```
public class Person {
    private String nombre;
    private String numero;

    public Person(String nombre, String numero) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return this.nombre;
    }

    public String getNumero() {
        return this.numero;
    }
}
```

Luego, iterarás sobre el archivo almacenando todos los registros de la forma:

```
FileReader fReader = new FileReader("personas.txt");
BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(fReader);

String line;
Vector<Person> people = new Vector<Person>();

while((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
      String[] data = line.split(":");

      people.add(new Person(data[0], data[1]));
}

bReader.close();
```

Luego iterarías sobre la colección hasta encontrar la persona que quieres y la eliminas de la forma:

```
String nombre = "Juan";

for(Person person : people) {
    if(person.getNombre().equals(nombre)) {
       people.remove(person);
       break;
    }
```

}

Y luego abrirías el archivo en forma de escritura truncándolo(borrando todo lo que contiene) y lo llenarías de vuelta con los datos que permanecieron en la colección de la forma:

```
FileWriter fWriter = new FileWriter("personas.txt");
for(Person person : people) {
    fWriter.write(person.getNombre() + ":" + person.getNumero());
}
fWriter.close();
```

Claro, no tomé en cuenta consideraciones como: Elementos con nombre repetidos, tildes, etc...

Pero creo que eso es suficiente para que entiendas la idea y la adaptes a lo que necesites.

Saludos. :)

Comment: Excelente respuesta, aunque sugiero que en lugar de usar un `Vector()` uses la interface `List()` así: `List<Person> people = new ArrayList();`

Comment: Desde Java 8, puedes usar un stream para leer un archivo mediante `[Files#lines](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-)` así te evitas el manejo manual de abrir el archivo, cerrarlo y leer cada línea, y te concentras solo en parsear cada línea y tu lógica de negocio.